# Set unique id to a computer for identifying on website

Tags: java, php, authentication, unique, uniqueidentifier

I´m developing a system that needs to identify the user computer before giving access to a certain page. In short: I would like to lock an account to a computer so that you can´t access a specific page unless you use a certain computer.

I´m able to set preferences on all computers if that helps. I don´t want to use cookies, session or something else that the user can remove.

Can this be achieved in some way?

Kind regards / H

Comment: Systems you mean like web application or program with GUI and all that :-)?

Comment: Do they log in?  Is just the PC that makes it unique?  What language are we talking about?

Comment: "that the user can remove" - how powerful is this user? Can they wipe the machine and reinstall the OS? If so, is this still meant to be an "authorised" computer?

Comment: An web application where the users log in. The user is not powerful at all. For example: It would be enough if we placed a file somewhere at the computer and check if that file exists.
I´m using php javascript but thinking about using java too.